# Pivot graph show only data based on cell colour

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-chart

I want to set up a pivot graph who only shows values based on the fill colour of the cell.
The graph should should the amount of cells with (e.g.) green, yellow, and red cells.

Can someone advise on how to go about that? I couldnt find a way to set a graph based on formatting as one does when filtering tables.

Thanks

Comment: Do these colors from data source created via condition formats? If not, I sugget you try Get.Cell function. For more please refer to "https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-get-cell-color/".

Comment: Yes, those are based on conditonal formatting. I'd like to aggregate them in the pivot graph based on background colour (like you can filter in tables by bg-colour)